# Is this a valid or invalid inference?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> 1. $(p \land q ) \iff (r \implies s)$
> 2. $(s \vee \neg t)$
>
> So, $\neg s \implies ((r \implies \neg p) \vee \neg t)$

My lecturer has written in our notes that this statement is invalid, but I'm not so sure. I've attached my workings and have found there to be a contradiction whilst using the 'no counterexample' method (i.e. assume the premise to be T whilst the conclusion F, if there is a contradiction then the statement is valid) to find the validity of this statement. Thus, I think this inference is valid.

My question is: is the above inference valid or not?

Thank you so much in advanced for your help! :)

[image: My workings out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will follow the instructor's notes and assume that the inference is *invalid*.

This means : assume the *premises* **T** and the *conclusion* **F**.

We may rewrite the conclusion as :

> $s \lor \lnot r \lor \lnot p \lor \lnot t \ $;

in order to have it **F** we need :

> $s=$ **F** and $r=p=t=$ **T**.

With this truth-assignment, the second premise : $s \lor \lnot t$ would be **F**.

Thus, the argument is *valid*.

---

If instead the sought conclusion is : $¬s \to ((r \to ¬p) \land ¬t)$, with the same approach we have two possibilities in order to "falsify" it; either :

> *(i)* $s=$ **F** and $t=$ **T**, or :
>
> *(ii)* $s=$ **F** and $r=p=$ **T**.

In the first case, again, we cannot satisfy the second premise.

In the second case, we have two variables "undefined" : $t$ and $q$.

The two premises are equivalent to :

> $($ **T** $\land q) \leftrightarrow$ **F**
>
> **F** $\lor \lnot t$.

Thus, if we set : $q=t=$ **F**, we can satisfy both premises and we have shown that the argument is *invalid*.

---

---

*Conclusion* :

> Is this a valid or invalid inference?

It depends on the formula (in this case : the conclusion) ...

Answer (score 1):

If s is not true, then (not t) has to be true, thus the inference is automatically true.

On a side note, I think that you may have made a typo...

Comment: Yes there is a typo in the notes. You can see I've circled the t:F as I keep getting t:T

Comment: p.s the typed notes are by my lecturer and the hand written notes are mine. :)

Comment: If you do not change the "and" to "or", the interference would be invalid and the counterexample is given in step 5... I think.

Comment: Hmmm, my lecturer emailed and told us to do exactly that: change the 'and' to the 'or'... I've emailed him and asked what's going on. Will update you when I have a reply from him! Thanks @user370007 for your reassurance! Been trying for ages to figure this one out :P

Comment: I'm quite interested in this too :D